# Why do these squares move together and not separately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I tried to create a simple shooting game in which the player controls the WASD keys and shoots at targets with pencils. Theoretically, the squares should fly to the right, push off the right edge, and fly back to the left, but for some reason, when the bottom square is pushed off, all the squares are pushed off at once (and I need them to push off themselves). What is the problem? What should I do?

````
import pygame
def inter(x1, y1, x2, y2, db1, db2):
    if x1 > x2-db1 and x1 < x2+db2 and y1 > y2-db1 and y1 < y2+db2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

import time

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 690))

screen = pygame.Surface((1000, 690))

player = pygame.Surface((40, 40))

zet = pygame.Surface((40, 40))

arrow = pygame.Surface((20, 40))

maks = pygame.Surface((40, 40))

seva = pygame.Surface((40, 40))

igor = pygame.Surface((40, 40))

kira = pygame.Surface((40, 40))

stas = pygame.Surface((40, 40))

count = 0

img_a = pygame.image.load('arrow.png')
img_p = pygame.image.load('player.png')
img_z = pygame.image.load('zet.png')
img_s = pygame.image.load('anonim.png')

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('monospace', 15)

a_x = 1000
a_y = 1000

strike = False 

z_x = 0
z_y = 0

x_p = 0
y_p = 650

m_x = 0
m_y = 50

s_x = 0
s_y = 100

i_x = 0
i_y = 150

k_x = 0
k_y = 200

st_x = 0
st_y = 250

right = True

done = False

while done == False:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_s:
            y_p += 5
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_w:
            y_p -= 5
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_a:
            x_p -= 5
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_d:
            x_p += 5
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            if strike == False:
                strike = True
                a_x = x_p
                a_y = y_p - 40
                


    if strike:
        a_y -= 1.5
        if a_y < 0:
            strike = False
            a_y = 1000
            a_x = 1000

    if inter(a_x,a_y, z_x, z_y, 20, 40):
        count += 1
        strike = False
        a_y = 1000
        a_x = 1000
        

    if right:
        z_x += 1
        if z_x > 960:
            z_x -=1
            right = False
    else:
        z_x -=1
        if z_x < 0:
            z_x += 1
            right = True
            

    if right:
        m_x += 1.5
        if m_x > 960:
            m_x -=1.5
            right = False
    else:
        m_x -=1.5
        if m_x < 0:
            m_x += 1.5
            right = True
            

    if right:
        s_x += 4
        if s_x > 960:
            s_x -=4
            right = False
    else:
        s_x -=4
        if s_x < 0:
            s_x += 4
            right = True
            

    if right:
        i_x += 3
        if i_x > 960:
            i_x -=3
            right = False
    else:
        i_x -=3
        if i_x < 0:
            i_x += 3
            right = True

            
    if right:
        k_x += 2
        if k_x > 960:
            k_x -=2
            right = False
    else:
        k_x -=2
        if k_x < 0:
            k_x += 2
            right = True
            

    if right:
        st_x += 2.5
        if st_x > 960:
            st_x -=2.5
            right = False
    else:
        st_x -=2.5
        if st_x < 0:
            st_x += 2.5
            right = True

    string = myfont.render('Счёт: '+str(count), 0, (255,0,0))
    
    screen.fill((0,225,0))
    arrow.blit(img_a, (0, 0))
    player.blit(img_p, (0, 0))
    zet.blit(img_z, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(string, (0, 50))
    screen.blit(arrow, (a_x, a_y))
    screen.blit(zet, (z_x, z_y))
    screen.blit(player, (x_p, y_p))
    screen.blit(maks, (m_x, m_y))
    screen.blit(seva, (s_x, s_y))
    screen.blit(igor, (i_x, i_y))
    screen.blit(kira, (k_x, k_y))
    screen.blit(stas, (st_x, st_y))
    window.blit(screen, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()```
````

Comment: This is where you start learning about debugging. We often write code that doesn't work the way we expect. There are several techniques to use here. One is to create a smaller example to work with that gets to the core ideas of the code that you are trying to figure out. Another is stepping through the code to verify that it does what you expect it to do. For creating small examples, see [mcve]. For debugging, read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I'm seeing is that there is only a single `right` variable, and that variable is being shared across *all* of your moving objects. Thus, once one of your objects sets `right` to `True`, all the other objects will see `right` as being `True`, as well. To fix this, each of your moving objects needs to have its own `right` variable.

Before you start making a bunch of variables called `a_right`, `k_right`, and so on, though, I'd recommend creating a class to represent your game objects, and storing those game objects in a list. You've got a *lot* of repetitive code in this program. Repetitive code makes it hard to find errors and can be a nightmare when you want to make changes to existing code. (Consider, for example, how you would need to change this code if you decided you wanted to have 500 things moving around the screen!)

If you're unfamiliar with classes and lists, the Python documentation has a good explanation of what they are and how to use them:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html